# Expansion `$` come with `*` and `@`

Tags: bash

I am learning bash expansion.

There are three types of expansions binding with `$`

1. Parameter Expansion
2. Command Substitution
3. Arithmetic Expansion.

I experiment on special symbol `$`.

```
    $ ls
    foo bar zoo
    $ echo $*
    #return nothing
    $ echo $@*
    foo bar zoo
```

What's going on with `@` and `$`

Additionally,

```
    $ ls $
    ls: $: No such file or directory
    $ ls $*
    foo bar zoo
    $ ls $a  #or any character
    foo bar zoo
```

I am confused about the mutablility of `$`.

How to interpret its behaviors above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some examples:

```
#!/bin/bash

a_function(){

    echo "positional parameters must be called in a script or a function"
    echo "positional parameters: $@"
    echo "positional parameters: $*"
    echo "directory's content:" *
}

a_function "one" "two" "three" "pan"
```

output:

```
positional parameters must be called in a script or a function
positional parameters: one two three pan
positional parameters: one two three pan
content of directory: <your current directory>
```

ps:

- `ls $a` ls variable a (empty), so simple ls
- `ls $*` ls positional parameters (empty), so simple ls
- `echo $@`* display $@ (empty) and directory"
- `ls: $`, error `$` alone

more infos: [doc bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)